# UIView animation broken in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I have a custom table view cell, designed in a seperate xib file, with a button called unitInfoBtn and a button called unitVisibilityCheckBox. When the table enters editing mode unitInfoBtn disaperas and unitVisibilityCheckBox appears. This worked fine in iOS 7 by using the follwing code:

```
-(void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super didTransitionToState:state];
    //deal with entering and exiting edit mode
    if (state == UITableViewCellStateEditingMask) //cell entered edit mode
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.unitInfoBtn.alpha = 0.0;
            self.unitInfoBtn.center = CGPointMake(unitInfoBtnOriginalXPos-50.0, self.unitInfoBtn.center.y);
            self.unitVisibilityCheckBox.alpha = 1.0;
        }];

    } else { //cell exited edit mode
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.unitInfoBtn.alpha = 1.0;
            self.unitInfoBtn.center = CGPointMake(unitInfoBtnOriginalXPos, self.unitInfoBtn.center.y);
            self.unitVisibilityCheckBox.alpha = 0.0;

        }];
    }       
}
```

However, on iOS 8 the code breaks and the alpha setting does not change. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that this code was always wrong:

```
if (state == UITableViewCellStateEditingMask)
```

As the name tells you, UITableViewCellStateEditingMask is a bitmask. That is because `state` is a bitmask. You do not compare bitmasks with `==`. You are looking for one particular bit within the mask. You have to use bitwise-and and compare to zero.

```
if ((state & UITableViewCellStateEditingMask) != 0)
```

That tells you that the Editing bit in `state` is set. If it is, you are editing.

The chances of `state` being *equal* to UITableViewCellStateEditingMask are slim. That would mean that this bit is set *and no others*. You can't count on that. I'm surprised this ever worked.

I'm not saying this is the cause of your difficulty (because I don't really understand what the problem is), but certainly you can't expect your code to work as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

The current states are

UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask (0), 
UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask (1), 
UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask (2), 
and 
UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask (3).

These states correspond to the values of the properties editing and showingDeleteConfirmation. It can be tested as follows:

if (!cell.editing && !cell.showingDeleteConfirmation)

{

```
// 0 - UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask
```

}

else if (cell.editing && !cell.showingDeleteConfirmation)

{

// 1 - UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask

}

else if (!cell.editing && cell.showingDeleteConfirmation)

{

// 2 - UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask

}

else if (cell.editing && cell.showingDeleteConfirmation)

{

```
// 3 - UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask
```

}

try with this instead of   if (state == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask) works fine.